# How can I open a LinkedIn connection profile from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api

I want to open a LinkedIn connection profile in LinkedIn app from my Android app. I tried the following method but didn't successful in opening the profile.

```
DeepLinkHelper deepLinkHelper = DeepLinkHelper.getInstance();

 deepLinkHelper.openOtherProfile(activity, memberId, deeplinkListener);
```

I think the issue is with the memberId, the documentation says

> memberId - obtained through an api call

I can't get the memberId for a connection through an api call because for that I have to apply for LinkedIn partnership program.

I want to open LinkedIn connection profile through an Id I obtained from connection profile URL i.e

> https://www.linkedin.com/in/mike-486a0834

So there any way I can open connection profile using id mike-486a0834 ?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using your own app, and you want to open up LinkedIn, then that is simple easy. Just use Intent class.

Comment: How ? If it is so simple, can explain it by an example and write a piece of code ?

Answer (score -1):

```
'String YourPageURL = "https://www.facebook.com/n/?YOUR_PAGE_NAME";
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(YourPageURL));

startActivity(browserIntent);'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.